# Google Cloud Function HTTP request connection times out

Tags: python, http, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, httprequest

I am performing an http request to the LibreNMS API via the following Python code:

```
import requests
TOKEN = './token.json'
def get_request(request_type):
    url = f'http://192.168.1.141/api/v0/{request_type}'
    with open(TOKEN,'r') as file:
        headers = json.load(file)
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        pass
    else:
        print(f"Failed to pull for {request_type}: {response.status_code}")
    return response.json()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dat = get_request('alerts') # pull alerts
```

The script runs perfectly on my local machine and quite fast. However when I try to deploy the scrip as a Google Cloud Function then `requests.get(url,headers=headers)` seems to time out. In the cloud logs of the function I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection( 
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request("
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen("
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()"
```

I have the same versions of `requests==2.28.1` and `urllib3==1.26.14` installed on my local machine and in the `requirements.txt` file of the cloud function. I thought the problem might lie here.

I am unsure if a cloud function can perform http requests to non-Google services. Perhaps this is the issue.

Please help me understand what is wrong with my function and/or deployment.

## Update

It seems that the issue lies within the fact that the address `192.168.1.141` was local. I have since replaced it with `librenms.bctechnologies.co.za:8050`. However, it seems like this too is not public as `response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)` keeps timing out.

Comment: Where is the service you are trying to request located?
The IP you provided looks like a private network ip available only from your computer (LAN)

Comment: I do not know where the service is located? I did not realize that this was important. So does `192.168.1.141` have a location that should correspond with the location that the cloud function is found at?

Comment: `192.168.1.141` is an address available only from your LAN so it is accessible by your computer but not from outside the LAN (aka Google Cloud). 
Is LibreNMS API (192.168.1.141) part of your Google Cloud deployment or or is it another service running on your computer or a different machine in the same network.

Comment: It would seem to be a windows virtual machine in the same network. Apologies, I did not realize until now that it was a LAN address. Can I access this address via Cloud Functions?

Comment: I have been accessing `192.168.1.141` without knowing what is it. Is this possible because my local machine was already on the LAN?

Comment: I have done quick reading and it seems that I need to set up a VPN (Virtual Private Network). It looks like this is an option in cloud functions under CONNECTIONS.

Comment: I have tried replacing the LAN address with `url = f'http://librenms.bctechnologies.co.za:8050/api/v0/{request_type}'` but it continues timing out on the cloud.

Comment: Opening your LAN to public network is risky. Are you sure this is what you want to do?
A better option for example may be running `LibreNMS` inside Google Cloud and access it privately. 
You can try testing with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) but I think you should effort more design in your infrastructure before you go to production.

Comment: @Guy Thank you very much for your comment and outlined solutions. Running LibreNMS inside Google Cloud sounds like a smart solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting @Guy comment as answer wherein running LibreNMS as a better option to access privately. The purpose of this post is to guide other users for this concern.

Just to add, if by chance you wanted to continue to access your Cloud Function using GCP Cloud VPN you can do this by creating first a connector which is [Serverless VPC access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#create-connector).

After the connector, the next step is by associating your Cloud Function to the connector that is created. You can do this by editing the Cloud Function and follow this steps in [Configure Cloud Functions to use a connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#functions).

Once Cloud Function is using the connector, the next step is to create a [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/configure-vpn-between-onprem-cloud). Just make sure that you will choose the network you use in your Serverless VPC access to have a connection to your Cloud Function.